Jest Test Fails with "Cannot Find Module 'mock-pdf.worker.js'" When Mocking pdf.worker.js for pdfjs-dist
I’m trying to write Jest tests for a project that uses pdfjs-dist to parse PDF files. I need to mock the worker file (pdf.worker.js) used by pdfjs-dist to avoid loading the real worker during tests. However, I keep running into this error:
Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot find module 'mock-pdf.worker.js' from 'node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js'".


What I’ve Tried:
Mocking the Worker File: I created a mock file at mocks/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.js with the following contents:
console.log("Mock pdf.worker.js loaded");
module.exports = {}; // Simulates an empty worker


Setting Module Name Mapper: In my jest.config.js file, I added the following to map the worker file:
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.js$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.js",
  },
};

Setting Worker in Tests: In my test file (tests/parse-resume-from-pdf.test.js), I added:
beforeEach(() => {
  const pdfjs = require("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf");
  pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = require.resolve(
    "__mocks__/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.js"
  );
});


Test Code: Here’s the relevant part of my test:
const { parseResumeFromPdf } = require("../src/parse-resume-from-pdf");
const path = require("path");

describe("Resume Parser - Parsing PDFs", () => {
  it("should parse a sample resume", async () => {
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../Waleed-Khali-Software_Engineer_Resume.pdf");
    let parsedResume;
    try {
      parsedResume = await parseResumeFromPdf(filePath);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error parsing resume:", error);
      throw error; // Fail the test if parsing fails
    }

    expect(parsedResume).toHaveProperty("profile");
    expect(parsedResume.profile).toHaveProperty("name");
    expect(parsedResume.profile.name).toBeTruthy();
  });
});


I see the log message Mock pdf.worker.js loaded, so I know the mock is being loaded.
If I use console.log(require.resolve("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.js")), it correctly resolves to my mock
My Questions:
Why does pdfjs-dist fail to find my mocked worker even though Jest resolves it correctly with moduleNameMapper?
Is there something I’m missing in the Jest configuration or the way I’m mocking the worker file?
How can I properly mock pdf.worker.js so that pdfjs-dist works in my tests?
